# How to check if a value is null or undefined in JavaScript (ES2020)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there a shorter way to checking if a value in JavaScript is `null` or `undefined` than this using new ES10 features like Nullish Coalescing?

```js
(value !== null && value !== undefined)
```

There were other questions like

1. [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)
2. [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'](/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)
3. [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

But they all use either loose equality (`==`), use jQuery or return `false` even if the value is `""`, `[]` or `0`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `value == null`

Comment: My project doesn't allow `==`

Comment: Does it prevent this with `eslint`? The `eqeqeq` ESLint rule has the `smart` option for allowing exactly this type of usage: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq

Comment: Yep, it worked, `eslint` didn't throw error for `value == null`, Thanks.

Comment: There's also `((value ?? null) !== null)` I guess?

Comment: `((value ?? null) !== null)` is a good solution for `null` but does not work with `undefined`

Comment: @DDomen but `undefined ?? null` produces `null`, and thus `(undefined ?? null) !== null` is false... have you tested it?

Comment: @jcalz after answering my own question I saw your comment, so deleted it. But undeleted it and added more information and my testing as a snippet. But Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jcalz sorry I was misleaded by `!==` and `===`, I've tested for the equality instead of inequality. It does work.

Comment: @jcalz `(value ?? null) !== null` might work but is totally weird. I would not recommend to write code like that, it's just a source of confusion. `value == null` is short, precise, well-known and idiomatic. Nothing about that changed with ES2020.

Comment: @Bergi agreed! I don't intend to recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eslint` will not throw an error for `value == null` if smart option is enabled

For project that doesn't have `smart` `eqeqeq` rule in `eslint` config,

There's a shorter way of doing it with Nullish Coalescing.

```js
(value ?? null) !== null
```

```js
let value

// undefined
console.log((value ?? null) !== null)

// null
value = null
console.log((value ?? null) !== null)

// ''
value = ''
console.log((value ?? null) !== null)

// 0
value = 0
console.log((value ?? null) !== null)

// []
value = []
console.log((value ?? null) !== null)
```

Comment: No, `(value ?? false) !== false` fails when `value === false`.  If the question were "can we check if a value is `null`, `undefined`, or `false`?" then sure.

Comment: Yes, `false` shouldn't be included. Thanks